# EaselJS clicking on the container how to prevent pressmove in the case of click or dblclick ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, easeljs

EaselJS 0.8.2  While clicking on the container pressmove event is also generating sometimes how to prevent pressmove in the case of click or dblclick ?

Comment: Pressmove only fires if you have pressed, then moved (and not released), whereas click/doubleclick fire when you release the mouse -- so by the time click/doubleclick has happened, the pressmove would have already fired. Maybe you are asking something else?

Comment: thank for your quick response. My problem is for one container I have defined click , dblclick and pressmove event . while click/dblclick on the container it is generating pressmove also sometime and because of my container is moving . how can I stop generating pressmove in the case of click/dblclick?

Comment: You will get pressmoves if you move the mouse before releasing it. This happens _before_ the click. Pressmove and click/double-click are not related at all, so you would have to code the behaviour you want -- for example ignoring pressmove if it happens within a normal click-threshold (50ms?), or preventing pressmove if you have already clicked once, and you move within a double-click threshold (200ms?).

Comment: thanks for your response and suggestion.